# how to retrieve data from DB and place in textbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Problem on placing data in textbox in griview]

The problem is initially I load the page with gridview having 1 row with each columns having a textbox. When I need to retrieve, I need the gridview to have the no of rows present same like DB such that it worked. But the gridview is not loaded with the datas...
The code I worked on....

```
int rowIndex = 0;
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt.Tables[1];
            LoadGridViewfromDB();
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox combobox = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gvmonoprixmasters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("combo");
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox sizes = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gvmonoprixmasters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("sizes");
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox barcodenumber = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gvmonoprixmasters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("barcodeno");
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox ratio = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gvmonoprixmasters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("ratio");
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox qty = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gvmonoprixmasters.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("qty");
                    combobox.Text = dt.Tables[1].Rows[i - 1]["Combo1"].ToString();
                    sizes.Text = dt.Tables[1].Rows[i - 1]["Sizes"].ToString();
                    barcodenumber.Text = dt.Tables[1].Rows[i - 1]["Barcode_Number"].ToString();
                    ratio.Text = dt.Tables[1].Rows[i - 1]["Ratio"].ToString();
                    qty.Text = dt.Tables[1].Rows[i - 1]["Quantity"].ToString();
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                gvmonoprixmasters.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                gvmonoprixmasters.DataBind();
            }
        }

protected void LoadGridViewfromDB()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable =(DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;

                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col4", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col5", typeof(string)));
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Col1"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Combo1"].ToString();
                dr["Col2"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Sizes"].ToString();
                dr["Col3"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Barcode_Number"].ToString();
                dr["Col4"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Ratio"].ToString();
                dr["Col5"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Quantity"].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            gvmonoprixmasters.DataSource = dt;
            gvmonoprixmasters.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aspx page

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COl1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In aspx.cs page use

```
 GridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables[1];
        GridView1.DataBind();
```